Как достать каждый файл по отдельности из медиагруппы в телеграм боте на aiogram?
Хочу, чтобы бот скачал каждый файл из отправленной ему медиагруппы, но что-то не найду как достать каждый файл по отдельности. Буду рад, если кто объяснит как работает медиагруппа в телеграм ботах.

Они там и есть по отдельности. Медиагруппа - это просто несколько сообщений, имеющих один идентификатор медиагруппы

В теории я это понимаю, но не знаю как на практике. Вроде бы это множество сообщений с медиафайлом, но как обратиться к каждому сообщению и отдельно к прикрепленному к нему файлу не очень смыслю.

Не очень понятно, что значит обратиться отдельно? К примеру, боту прилетает 10 фото, он их будет получать как 10 отдельных апейтов, в которых указан одинаковый media_group_id. Если нужно сохранить, пишем хендлер, который будет реагировать на фото, пишем необходимый код для сохранения фото. И все эти 10 апдейтов попадут в этот хендлер по очереди
